# Special case of noetherian space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space  is called Noetherian if it satisfies the descending chain condition for closed subsets. Now let $X $ be a topological space, and there exists a fix natural number $n $ such that for every chain $...\subseteq Y_i... \subseteq Y_2 \subseteq Y_1 $, we have $Y_n=Y_{n+1}=...$. I want to know that if this property is well known and important, or is there any equivalent condition for this?

Comment: Chain of what? If its chain of open sets, it is almost certainly "Artinian"(or at least should be). A prime spectrum of a ring is Noetherian as a topological space if and only if the ring is Noetherian as a ring. Then, a prime spectrum of a ring would be "Artinian" if and only if the ring was Artinian.

Comment: I think that, if $X$ is a Zariski closed set and $Y_i$ are closed subsets, then [the dimension of $X$ as an algebraic variety is $\le n-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety). In that context, it is sometimes referred to as "Krull dimension" (though it appears this is more akin to its algebraic definition).